the rule `values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined`. this rule looks doing partiality
This is my first Rust code:
fn display<'a, 'b>(x: &'a String, y: &'b String) -> impl FnOnce() -> (&'a String, &'b String) {
    move || (x, y)
}

fn main() {
    let _closure;
    let s1 = String::from("Hello");
    let s2 = String::from("World");

    _closure = display(&s1, &s2);

    let (ref1, ref2) = _closure();

    println!("{} {}", ref1, ref2);
}

It doesn't compile this is the compiler error:
$ cargo run --verbose
       Dirty clousers v0.1.0 (/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers): the file `src/main.rs` has changed (1735367706.253806400s, 5m 2s after last build at 1735367404.000000000s)
   Compiling clousers v0.1.0 (/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers)
     Running `/home/pankaj/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name clousers --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=125 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 --check-cfg 'cfg(docsrs)' --check-cfg 'cfg(feature, values())' -C metadata=6985c523bb27130d -C extra-filename=-6985c523bb27130d --out-dir '/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers/target/debug/deps' -C 'incremental=/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers/target/debug/incremental' -L 'dependency=/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers/target/debug/deps'`
error[E0597]: `s1` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:24
   |
7  |     let s1 = String::from("Hello");
   |         -- binding `s1` declared here
...
10 |     _closure = display(&s1, &s2);
   |                        ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
15 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `s1` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `_closure` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl FnOnce() -> (&String, &String)`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined

error[E0597]: `s2` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:29
   |
8  |     let s2 = String::from("World");
   |         -- binding `s2` declared here
9  |
10 |     _closure = display(&s1, &s2);
   |                             ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
15 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `s2` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `_closure` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl FnOnce() -> (&String, &String)`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `clousers` (bin "clousers") due to 2 previous errors

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/pankaj/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name clousers --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=125 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 --check-cfg 'cfg(docsrs)' --check-cfg 'cfg(feature, values())' -C metadata=6985c523bb27130d -C extra-filename=-6985c523bb27130d --out-dir '/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers/target/debug/deps' -C 'incremental=/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers/target/debug/incremental' -L 'dependency=/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers/target/debug/deps'` (exit status: 1)
pankaj@JARVIS:/mnt/d/Pankaj Batham/Coding PlayGround/Rust Coding Practice/clousers$ 

It looks that values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined as per the compiler's output, but then I tried this second Rust code to verify:
fn main() {
    let reference_holder;

    let referenced_data = String::from("Hello World!...");

    reference_holder = &referenced_data;

    println!("{}", reference_holder);
}

And this compiles and runs fine.
I can't understand that if declaring _closure before the data it refers to, causes an error, then in my second code example, why doesn't declaring reference_holder before referenced_data cause an error?
When I declare and initialize the variable _closure on the same line, after the declaration of s1 & s2 the error disappears:
let _closure = display(&s1, &s2);

I am unable to understand the rule being applied in both examples and why one compiles while the other doesn't?
I tried reading Rusts official documentation, but did not get a satisfactory answer.
According to the scoping based dropping rule, my second code example should also fail to compile, but it didn't. Why does the scoping based dropping rule looks like it's working differently?

The explanation runs into a surprising amount of commonly unheard things in the Rust type system!
First, as you've correctly noticed, the error depends on _closure being declared before s1 and s2. Order of declarations impacts drop order (variables are dropped by reverse order of their declarations). This is the first hint.
The second hint comes from the fact that, as you've also noticed yourself, impl Trait is required to produce the error. Without impl Trait (in function return type) the error does not reproduce. impl Trait also affects destructors, or more precisely, it affects how the compiler thinks about destructors. Without impl Traits, (and with non-lexical lifetimes), variables are considered to have a destructor if they have one (i.e. they implement Drop or have a field that does, recursively). But things that are returned as impl Trait are always considered to have a destructor, due to impl Trait's need to be opaque.
And here you may ask: can we make the compiler consider impl Trait to not have a destructor, to see how this will impact our code? And the answer is, not exactly, but here yes! The compiler knows that Copy and Drop are mutually exclusive, so if you have an impl Trait + Copy it won't consider it to implement Drop.
And here's our little test, armed with that knowledge:
fn display<'a, 'b>(
    x: &'a String,
    y: &'b String,
) -> impl FnOnce() -> (&'a String, &'b String) + Copy {
    move || (x, y)
}

fn main() {
    let _closure;
    let s1 = String::from("Hello");
    let s2 = String::from("World");

    _closure = display(&s1, &s2);

    let (ref1, ref2) = _closure();

    println!("{} {}", ref1, ref2);
}

And it compiles fine (playground). Which means that our guess was correct, and this has something to do with Drop. What's left is to combine all the pieces.
And the answer is that in the first snippet, the compiler behaves as if impl FnOnce had implemented Drop. As such, it cannot allow it to be dropped after the things it contains references to (s1 and s2). But in the second case, it knows it does not implement Drop, so it can be freely "dropped" even after s1 and s2.

Why does the compiler error imply that _closure() doesn't consume _closure? It's only FnOnce so it should, right?

@kmdreko Good question! I think this about what happens when unwinding, but I'll keep checking.

Ah, that would make sense

It seems that if there are n variables declared within a scope, the order in which the variables implementing the Drop trait are declared matters. Specifically, the variables holding data must be declared before those holding references to that data, in accordance with the scoping-based dropping rule. Is that correct?

@PankajBatham Yes, that's because variables are dropped in reverse order.

See also RFC 1327. References have the may_dangle attribute, which allows them to be dropped after the value they reference, impl Trait doesn't have this attribute and so must be dropped first.

The error in the first example is from the borrow checker. The key insight is that the compiler - or more specifically the borrow checker - knows that references do not access the value they are referencing when dropped (references have no drop logic).
So yes, the drop order rules means the reference is dropped after the referent, but the borrow checker knows this cannot cause a use-after-free error and doesn't emit an error. See "non-lexical lifetimes" for more details.
Another insight is that the closure in the first example only holds references and wouldn't have any drop logic so it could be allowed under a similar principle. However, because you used an opaque type (impl FnOnce), the compiler is forced to be conservative and assume there is drop logic that may access the references. So the first sample emits an error.

It seems that if there are n variables declared within a scope, the order in which the variables implementing the Drop trait are declared matters. Specifically, the variables holding data must be declared before those holding references to that data, in accordance with the scoping-based dropping rule. Is that correct?
